# Why can't I use soap.request() in Adobe Reader X?

Tags: pdf, acrobat, livecycle, adobe-reader

I have a small PDF that uses `soap.request()` to submit data

This works fine under Adobe Acrobat. I've exported the file with extended Reader abilities,
but once I try to invoke `soap.request()`, I'm getting the following error

> Security settings prevent access to this property or method

Any ideas?

I've read abit and it seems like I need to use Adobe Livecycle Reader extentions in order to create a PDF that has this ability, is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have personal experience with calling a SOAP webservice in Adobe Reader but [this forums.adobe.com thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/718355?start=0&tstart=0) confirms your assumption.

Comment: Thanks bassim. I've finished installing LiveCycle a few hours ago - Reader extentions provided in the Livecycle server do allow extending the use of webservices under Reader X

Answer (score 0):

from the Adobe documentation (SOAP) - [API documentation](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/11/Acrobat11_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat11_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.89.1147.html)

SOAP is only available in : "...in **Acrobat Pro** and **Acrobat Standard** and for documents *with Form Export Rights open in Adobe Reader 6.0 or later*."

Comment: Thanks for answering this, but this question is 5 years old :)

Comment: Happened that I hit the wall in this SOAP issue today. :)